# How do I query with url parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js and trying to check if an e-mail is already taken by sending the email as a url parameter from iOS app. It is not working, not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am unable to console.log the email parameter in VSCode sent from the front-end, it DOES print in XCODE ( *http://localhost:3000/api/user/email/test@gmail.com* ) and I know the backend is getting the GET request.

My router code is:

```
const express = require(`express`)
const router = new express.Router()
const User = require(`../models/user-model`)   //  import User model

router.get(`/api/user/email/:email`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params) // does NOT print email: test@gmail.com
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne(req.params.email)

        if (user) {
            console.log(user._id)
            res.send({ available: false })
        } else {
            res.send({available: true})
        }
    } catch {
        res.status(404).send()
    }
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: "does NOT print email: test@gmail.com" — While it is always useful to know when expected behavour doesn't occur, you really should tell us what behaviour you do get. Does it print `undefined`? `{}`? Something else? Does the line never get called?

Comment: How are you mounting your router onto your application? Is your URL actually correct once you take that into account?

Comment: @Quentin, It looks like the targeted route isn't being called ( I added a console.log('email route') and it isn't logging ) so I need to look into my Swift code and double check everything...

Comment: Ignore the swift code. Either the request isn't being made to `http://localhost:3000/api/user/email/test@gmail.com` (in which case trigger a request there manually with a browser) or that's the wrong URL (see my previous comment).

Comment: ugh I forgot to add 'module.exports = router' ! My bad!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Editing this.. I dont have enough points to comment.. your route seems to be fine, maybe you are not telling your application to use this route, somewhere before starting your application you should have something like:

```
this.app = new express();
...
this.app.use('/api', MailRouter); //<=== Adding your required mail route
...
```

I use to split url one parte here (/api) and the other one in the router (/user/email/:email). I'm not sure how to do it by adding it fully to the router (Maybe '/' maybe '')

Comment: They aren't using a URL like that. There's nothing wrong with an approach using params.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't telling my app to use the route!

Answer (score 0):

```
         const express = require(`express`)
     const app = new express();
     app.get(`/api/user/email/:email`, async (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.params) // does NOT print email: test@gmail.com
     try {
     // const user = await User.findOne(req.params.email)
     const user = {_id:123};
     if (user) {
        console.log(user._id)
        res.send({ available: false })
     } else {
        res.send({available: true})
     }
     } catch {
     res.status(404).send()
     }
     })

    app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("running");
    })
```